# Scala Future calling lazy method inside block is not working

Tags: scala

**Problem:** 
I am trying to call lazy function(function assigned to lazy val) inside Future block and it is not behaving as expected but when i execute the function directly inside the block it is working as expected. Not sure if am missing any.

**Working Code:** 
Below is the code working as expected when i execute the method directly inside Future block

```
 implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService {
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8)
  }

  def execute1() = {
    Thread.sleep(4000); println("Completed 1!!!")
    1
  }
  def execute2() = {
    Thread.sleep(3000); println("Completed 2!!!")
    2
  }
  def execute3() = {
    Thread.sleep(2000); println("Completed 3!!!")
    3
  }
  def execute4() = {
    Thread.sleep(1000);  println("Completed 4!!!")
    4
  }
  val future1 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(execute1())
  val future2 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(execute2())
  val future3 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(execute3())
  val future4 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(execute4())

  val result = for { r1 <- future1
       r2 <- future2
       r3 <- future3
       r4 <- future4

  } yield {
    println(r1+","+r2+","+r3+","+r4)
  }
  StdIn.readLine()
  sys.exit()
```

When the above code is executed, the methods are executed in order "execute4,execute3,execute2,execute1" which is as expected.

**Not Working Code:**
In the above code, when i trying assigning the "execute" method to lazy variable and refer that variable inside Future block it is behaving differently. It is executed in 1,4,3,2 order.. Please see below code

```
  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService {
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8)
  }

  def execute1() = {
    Thread.sleep(4000); println("Completed 1!!!")
    1
  }
  def execute2() = {
    Thread.sleep(3000); println("Completed 2!!!")
    2
  }

  def execute3() = {
    Thread.sleep(2000); println("Completed 3!!!")
    3
  }

  def execute4() = {
    Thread.sleep(1000); println("Completed 4!!!")
    4
  }

  lazy val e1 = execute1()
  lazy val e2 = execute2()
  lazy val e3 = execute3()
  lazy val e4 = execute4()

  val future1 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(e1)
  val future2 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(e2)
  val future3 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(e3)
  val future4 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(e4)

  val result = for { r1 <- future1
       r2 <- future2
       r3 <- future3
       r4 <- future4

  } yield {
    println(r1+","+r2+","+r3+","+r4)
  }

  StdIn.readLine()
  sys.exit()
```

**Expected Behavior:** Since the functions(e1,e2,e3,e4) are referred as Lazy, it should be executed inside Future block upon calling and should behave same as the working code. Weird behavior i notice is it executes execute1() method synchronously and rest of the methods asynchronously.. Any guidance or suggestion will be great to me..

**Output I am Expecting:** 
Regardless of "i execute the method inside Future block"(or) "make the method as lazy outside the Future block and call inside the Future block" should yield me the same result.. As per my example, the output i am expecting is "the order of method execution(asynchronously) as execute4(),execute3(),execute2() and execute(1)"

**To simplify the example**.. 
Future Execution is different in below two approach.. In both the approach, i am expecting same output

```
//Approach#1 
def method() = {
}

Future{
 method()
}

//Approach#2
lazy val lazyMethod = method()

Future {
    lazyMethod()
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you minimize your example and what output you are expecting?

Comment: Hi Viktor.. Added the output i m expecting.. Regarding my example being long, i have created multiple methods to demonstrate the asynchronous behavior and all the methods is having similar execution.. please let me know if you still want to cut it down..

Comment: There is no guaranty in execution order in both cases as ‘Future’ can start executing block at any time right after it created. You dont even need ‘for’ for this.

Comment: I would rather mention it is as order of completion.. I am expecting the order of completion since I have given Sleep time inside method differently for each method so that method with less sleep time gets finished first. I am able to get this order of completion consistently and my problem is statement is when i execute a lazy method(declared outside Future) in Future, it is behaving differently than i call the method directly inside Future.. former takes long time to run since first method is executed synchronously and later is finished as expected..

Comment: as far as i know you can't expect the execution of the future block it can execute when ever it will get the CPU burst cycle.

Comment: yeah i understand that part.. i am describing a different problem.. It is taking longer time when lazy method is referred inside future block than executing directly.. if you could get a chance to execute the example, you might get glimpse of it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the code is working as expected. Let me explain.

First comes the `for`, when you did,

```
val result = for {
  r1 <- future1
  r2 <- future2
  r3 <- future3
  r4 <- future4
} yield {
  println(r1+","+r2+","+r3+","+r4)
}
```

You are roughly doing,

```
val result = 
  future1.flatMap(r1 =>
    future2.flatMap(r2 =>
      future3.flatMap(r3 =>
        future4.map(r4 =>
          println(r1+","+r2+","+r3+","+r4)
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

Which means you are "accessing" the values computed by these futures only after you have accessed the value of the previous one.

Now comes the `Future.apply` which takes a `body: => T` as argument and gives you a `Future[T]` but the thing is that this `body` will start executing as soon as you create the future.

So, In your first implementation when you did,

```
val future1 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(execute1())
val future2 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(execute2())
val future3 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(execute3())
val future4 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(execute4())
```

All these `futuresI's` began executing your `executeI's` at this point. So, the `println` inside these `executeI's` will be executed `x ms` after this, irrespective of when you try to access the value inside any of these futures.

Now, comes the `lazy`. So when you declare something like this,

```
val laxy x = {
  println("accessing lazy x")
  5
}
```

The block will be executed only when you access `x` for the first time.

And when you are doing this,

```
val future1 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(e1)
val future2 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(e2)
val future3 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(e3)
val future4 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(e4)
```

You are still not "accessing" any of these `lazy` `eI's` but as you know that each future starts computing as soon as it is created. So when these futures start executing they will "access" these `eI's`.

To understand it better, lets change our `executeI's` as following,

```
def execute1() = {
  println("Started 1!!! " + System.currentTimeMillis())
  Thread.sleep(4000)
  println("Completed 1!!! " + System.currentTimeMillis())
  1
}
```

And you will notice that all of these `eI's` are executing sequentially.

This is because all these `eI's` will be evaluated in the thread where these were defined and not in the thread executing the Future. So these `Thread.sleep` will block the current thread and will be evaluated in a non-deterministic order (owing to some probable optimizations), which co-incidentally happens to be 1, 4, 3, 2.

But if you change the order of future to,

```
val future1 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(e1)
val future4 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(e4)
val future2 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(e2)
val future3 : Future[Int] = Future.apply(e3)
```

It will become 1, 3, 2, 4.

Comment: Is there way to execute the lazy eI's as part of "Future" block rather "for" block and make it behave as the first implementation.. My requirement is to execute all the 5 lazy eI's in parallel..

Comment: Never mind.. I got it working using def instead lazy val.. i assumed lazy val to be working differently. my bad.. thanks for your response

Comment: @Sarvesh-kumar-singh why we `are not "accessing" any of these lazy eI's `. It seems that we are: `lazy val x = { println("accessing lazy x") }; Future(x)`. It prints the message.

Comment: Oh yeah.. I tried as Bogdan described.. I tried printing the lazy val inside Futue block(which should execute the function per say) but still it is same behavior.. As long as I know if you reference a lazy val is good enough to execute it.. Inside for comprehension I m just flatmapping to wait for previous  and access the value and the lazy Val should have been invoked as part of referencing in Future block itself..

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko You are right, the answer in its current wordings does not convey the correct reasoning. Updated the answer.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I'm wondering why they are `evaluated in the thread where these were defined`. Is this a rule for def's?

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko The behaviour should be this behaviour but it seems that it is not correct wording either. So, we have a lazy value `x : T` which is supposed to be evaluated in a `block: => T` which will be evaluated in some other thread. Strange behaviour indeed. What I mean to say is that all these `eI's` will be evaluated one-by-one (no parallelism) as if they were in the same thread (but actual threads will be different). How do we write this in correct words?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh looks like we just cannot say what order should or shouldn't be because there is no rules saying there must be an order at all in both cases. The fact that we have some execution order changed after we change Future creation order doesn't mean that we can control it because each block is executed in its own thread independently. You can check it by adding `println( Thread.currentThread().getId)` to each block. So it happen because of some internal implementations/optimization staff and we cannot say that there will be the same order on next run on other env.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh it may change if you change ExecutorService implementation for example. or change number of threads in there.

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko Yes, the order is non-deterministic but the mutually-exclusive-execution is a consistent property irrespective of pool-size.

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko As far as I know, this mutual-exclusion is because of `scala.concurent.BlockContext.blockOn[T](thunk: =>T)`.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I think it is getting executed in parallel in "Lazy" implementation as well.. When i print the `println( Thread.currentThread().getId)` (as Bogdan mentioned) inside the executeI block and execute it, each eI method is executed in different thread but e1 method is executed first sequentially and rest of the methods are executed in parallel.Order is 1,4,3,2 because 4,3,2 are done in parallell and completion order is due to sleep time differences(4 is lower and 2 is higher).

Comment: I feel like it's bug when we use lazy val inside Future block.. either it should be sequential as per your theory or parallel as lazy val is referenced in Future block but it looks to be mix of both.